# unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$BODY$

Tags: postgresql

I do not know why I am getting the following error message:

> unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$BODY$

Here is my SQL query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cdr_insert_function()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    if 
        (new.call_date >= '2014-01-01' and new.call_date <'2015-01-01') then
        insert into cdr_2014 values(new.*);
    elseif 
        (new.call_date >= '2015-01-01' and new.call_date <'2016-01-01') then
        insert into cdr_2015 values (new.*);
    elseif 
        (new.call_date >= '2016-01-01' and new.call_date < '2017-01-01') then
        insert into cdr_2016 values (new.*);
    elseif 
        (new.call_date >='2017-01-01' and new.call_date <'2018-01-01') then
        insert into cdr_2017 values (new.*);
    elseif 
        (new.call_date >='2018-01-01' and new.call_date <'2019-01-01') then
        insert into cdr_2018 values (new.*);
    elseif 
        (new.call_date >='2019-01-01' and new.call_date <'2020-01-01') then
        insert into cdr_2019 values (new.*);
    elseif 
        (new.call_date >='2020-01-01' and new.call_date <'2021-01-01') then
        insert into cdr_2020 values (new.*);
    elseif 
        (new.call_date >='2021-01-01' and new.call_date <'2022-01-01') then
        insert into cdr_2021 values (new.*);
    else
        raise exception 'Something is wrong, so an exception has been raised. Probably out of date range. Fix cdr_insert_function() !';
    end if;
    return null;
end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

It looks like it is terminated to me.

Comment: The statement is syntactically correct. Probably this is an issue with your client app, did you try it in psql?

Comment: I did, it works there, something is wrong with the program I'm using, I'm assuming.

Comment: So which SQL client **are** you using?

Comment: We are using Pentaho.

Comment: I'm getting the same in DBeaver 5.0.x with "Execute SQL script"; using `psql` and loading the script with `\i dump.sql` worked.